# How to concatenate strings in Entity Framework Query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I want to perform the following query in Entity framework 6. Although i tried converting integer field to strings but it did not worked out.

```
using (var context = new HospitalEntities())
            {
                var ibed = from u in context.Employee
                           where u.EmployeeId == employeeId
                               select new
                               {
                                   _empId = u.EmployeeId,
                                   _name =Convert.ToString(u.Code) + u.EmployeeName


                               };
```

Model Class:

```
public class Employee
{

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In **EF 6** you need to use **System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions** (NOT System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions which was used in prior versions)

```
using (var context = new HospitalEntities())
{
var ibed = from u in context.Employee
where u.EmployeeId == employeeId
select new
{
      _empId = u.EmployeeId,
      _name = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.StringConvert((int?) u.Code) + u.EmployeeName


};
```

I'm using the long name here for emphasis.  In prior projects you'll just replace the includes.  Again, this is for **Entity Framework 6** when trying to do **StringConvert** or other SQL functions.

```
//using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
```

Comment: As of EF 6.1 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx) you can now concat any primitive type.. e.g  entity.MyInt + entity.MyStr + "hello" and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert`

```
_name =SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)u.Code) + u.EmployeeName
```